# Cookies with a jquery class switcher?

Tags: jquery, class, switchers

I really can't figure out how to use cookies with this class switcher I got here

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.switch_thumb").toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass("swap");
        $(".main").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(300).addClass("main2");
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).addClass("swap");
        $(".main2").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(300).addClass("main3");
        });

    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("swap");
        $(".main").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(300).removeClass("main3");
    $(this).fadeIn(300).removeClass("main2");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Any tips?

---

It's a script that flips between 3 views (3 different backgrounds) and I want it to remember the last chosen background

Comment: "use cookies" is not really sufficient to tell us what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do here without a link to the page; I'd suggest restructuring the code to be a single function called via the click method.

You can then call that function on document ready too switching on the cookie which you could set with the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie); therefore maintaining the current selection across different pages which I think is your intended functionality?